# Maven goal / plugin to touch a file

Tags: java, file, maven, glassfish, reload

I'm looking for a way to touch a file using maven.
The specific user case for this is touching a `.reload` file in order to force Glassfish to redeploy an Application.

Is there any built-in functionality or plugin able to touch a file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These possibilities come to mind:

- Use the [antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and the
  [`<touch>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html) task
- [Use the GMaven plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code) and touch the file programmatically using Groovy